# How to get user input from html type date

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to get the input from an HTML input type date and then make the input a PHP variable which can then be used in a select query. But I'm struggling to get the input does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Here is my code that's relevant to the question also post_date in the database is type DATE

```php
if (isset($_POST['current_date'])) {
    $date = $_POST['current_date'];
    $_SESSION['session_date'] = $date;
}
else{
    $_SESSION['session_date'] = date('Y-m-d');
}

$query = "SELECT post_id, symptom, medication, day_rating, day_comment, username, post_date FROM Posts WHERE username ='".$_SESSION['username']."' AND post_date = '".$_SESSION['session_date']."'";
$result = $link->query($query);

if ($result->num_rows > 0){
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $symptom = $row["symptom"];
        $medication = $row["medication"];
        $day_rating = $row["day_rating"];
        $day_comment = $row["day_comment"];
    }
}
else{
    $symptom = "No symptoms recorded for this day.";
    $medication = "No medications recorded for this day.";
    $day_rating = 0;
    $day_comment = "No comments recorded for this day.";
}
```

```html
<input class="home-input" type="date" name="current_date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" />
```

Comment: Do you start the session? Do you execute the query? Can you provide more details about "where I'm going wrong"? You are open to SQL injections. `value="<?php date('Y-m-d');; ?>"` also does nothing, you'd need to `echo` the `date` string

Comment: @jszobody thats left over from an attempt to fix my issue forgot to change it back before posting this

Comment: @user3783243 same as what i said to jszobody thats just not been changed from a previous attempt at solving this i'll update the code also yes when a user logs it starts a session and the query is executed i just didnt think it was relevant to the question

Comment: How did submit you form? It's a POST form or a GET form?

Comment: @g4li its a POST form. the date displayed on the html date input updates to the date selected but the session variable doesnt seem to get updated

Comment: I think ive fixed the issue thanks for the help anyway